# Поворот оружия в сторону Touch на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Каким образом сделать, так чтобы оружие моего персонажа дулом было повернуто в сторону моего пальца (тача) и следило за ним, когда вожу по экрану.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootPoint : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
        touchPosition.z = 0f;
        // transform.localRotation = touchPosition;
        transform.rotation = ????????????
   }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Unity у Transform есть метод [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) - по названию видно, что он делает :)
Поэкспериментируйте с ним. Скорее всего, если у вас 2d игра, вам придётся доворачивать сам объект по какой-то из осей, чтобы он смотрел в экран нужным ребром.

Comment: почти получилось, только оружие поворачивается осью Z в сторону touchPosition, а надо x осью

Comment: а всё, сделал, сори)

Comment: @PinPin, примите ответ тогда, чтобы вопрос закрылся)

Answer (score 1):

В двумерном случае угол, соответствующий направлению вектора от точки A (персонаж) до точки B (точка, соответствующая касанию):

```
 Fi = Math.atan2(B.Y - A.Y, B.X - A.X)
```

Comment: Я не понял ваш код? Fi это что? Вместо transform.rotation?

Comment: Fi это угол направления. Чтобы получить, насколько нужно повернуть персонажа   - нужно знать его текущее направление. Или, если оно всегда он нуля, напрямую использовать данный угол. Обычно atan2 выдаёт его в радианах, а как в вашем Unity (радианы или градусы) - сами смотрите.

Comment: Приведу аналогию - идёшь по компасу по азимуту 30 градусов. Видишь ориентир по азимуту 45. Поворачиваешь на +15 градусов. Идёшь по азимуту 45 градусов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой простенький код получился, если кому понадобится.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootPoint : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        LookAt();
    }

    void LookAt()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2(touchPosition.x - transform.position.x, touchPosition.y - transform.position.y);
            transform.right = direction;
        }
    }
}
```